# Reset unique_ptr for protected virtual destructor base class

Tags: c++

I'm in a situation where in I've to create an object of either type `A` or `B` depending on a condition. Both `A` and `B` inherit from the same base class, in this case - `Base`. The base class has a virtual protected destructor.

The variable is declared as `std::unique_ptr<Base> member` and then depending on the condition, I use either `std::make_unique<A>` or `std::make_unique<B>`.

I'm calling `member.reset()` but getting a compiler error since the destructor is declared protected. But what I don't understand is why is the compiler not able to call the correct destructor since the destructor is also declared virtual.

But is there some other way to fix this? And why exactly does the virtual destructor not help here?

Full code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;

protected:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

private:
    int a;
};

class A : public Base
{
};

class B : public Base
{
};

unique_ptr<Base> get_object(bool cond) {
    if (cond) {
        return make_unique<A>();
    } else {
        return make_unique<B>(); 
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    bool cond;
    cin >> cond;

    unique_ptr<Base> a_or_b = get_object(cond);
    a_or_b.reset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: Base destructor should be declared as virtual.

Comment: `unique_ptr` cannot call protected members any more than `shared_ptr` can.  It's not a friend of the class.  You would have a similar problem if you tried to make the constructor protected.    In the end, `unique_ptr` needs some public member of the class in order to do cleanup work.

Comment: It seems that you can add a friend declaration inside your `Base` class like `friend  std::default_delete<Base>;` but in practice it has little useful purpose (over making the destructor public) as it is then possible to delete object of that type anyway.

Comment: Why is the destructor `protected` instead of `public`? Also you say that the destructor is `virtual`, but it is not `virtual` in your shown code.

Comment: @Joe In this case replacing `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr` and `make_unique` with `make_shared` will actually happen to work, because the ownership group created with `make_shared<T>` will destroy the object with a pointer to the original type `T`, no matter the type of the shared pointer calling the destructor. But I don't see that being an appropriate solution.

Comment: @user17732522 That was a typo, I've added the `virtual` keyword back.

Comment: @user17732522 with regards to what you described for `shared_ptr`, it is exactly what I expected `unique_ptr` to do as well, but it doesn't.

Comment: @user17732522 How can that "ownership group" possibly get access to a protected function when it is not a friend of the class?

Comment: @KartikAnand `std::unique_ptr` doesn't do it this way because that would significantly complicate the implementation and runtime overhead. For `shared_ptr` there is already significant overhead to implement the shared ownership and it can basically be done as part of that.

Comment: @Joe `std::make_shared` will store a type-erased deleter in the control block which calls the `delete` expression on the original pointer type. A protected member function is never called from a shared_ptr.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, but the original pointer type's destructor is *protected*.  Meaning the deleter, which is not a friend of the class should not be able to access it.  I am not trying to be argumentative but I don't see how that could possibly work.

Comment: @Joe The base class destructor is `protected`. The derived class destructors are (implicly-declared) `public`.

Comment: @user17732522.  I'll be damned.  I just tested to confirm and you are absolutely right.   I totally had that wrong.  I thought that a derived class not overriding a base-class' protected destructor would leave it protected.  But it makes it automatically public.  Did not realize that.  (In fact, I'm not sure I like it but that's beside the point).  Granted, I've never had cause to make a destructor protected but I've been doing C++ for a very long time so I should have known better.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe All the implicitly-declared member functions are always `public`, but it is probably not helping that explicitly-inherited constructors actually take on the accessibility in the base class (and ignore the specifier at the inheriting `using` declaration completely). I guess C++ is not really known for its consistent and intuitive rules...

Comment: @Phil1970: You cannot rely portably on `friend` here. `std::default_delete<Base>` might forward the destruction to pimpl/helper functions internally.

Answer (score 1):

> The base class has a virtual protected destructor.

I don't see any point in that. Making the destructor `protected` disallows destroying objects through base class pointers. This makes sense as a protection mechanism if doing so would cause undefined behavior (i.e. if the destructor is non-`virtual` and the most-derived type different from the base class type).

However, making the destructor `virtual` intents it to be called through the base class pointer in order to destruct also possibly derived class objects, contradicting the effect of `protected`.

`std::unique_ptr` is unable to destroy the object through the base class pointer because of the reason given above. `virtual` does not change that calling the destructor through the base class pointer is disallowed.

See also the [C++ core guidelines rule C.35](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-non-virtual).

Comment: But doesn't having a `virtual` destructor effectively mean that the compiler would consult the vtable and call the method on the correct object. So, in this case when `unique_ptr` does go to delete the object, the `virtual` should make sure that the compiler gets the correct derived class object and call the destructor on that ?

Comment: @KartikAnand Yes, but making it also `protected` is telling the compiler to not allow anyone that isn't a derived class or a `friend` to do that.

Comment: @KartikAnand In case that is part of the confusion: Accessibility is checked at compile-time on the actual function that the code calls (before virtual dispatch). The compiler can't possibly know which function is actually called at runtime after the dispatch, so it can't perform an accessibility check on that.

Comment: Yeah this clears it up, since the accessibility check is happening at compile time itself, I'm getting this error even though during run time it should be fine. Is there a way around this then ?

Comment: @KartikAnand The way around this is to not declare the base class destructor `protected` and `virtual`, but only `virtual`. I have yet to see any reason for having both.

Comment: Also in my case, the Base class is coming from a library which I cannot change and I don't think a shared pointer would also work since the already existing code is using a `unique_ptr`, what would you suggest in this case ? I can either create different variables to store the two types or I was thinking of introducing a class in the middle which has a normal public destructor.

Comment: @KartikAnand Either this is a mistake in the library or they have a good reason to specifically forbid you from doing what you are trying to do here. I can't really think of such a reason (if the destructor is also `virtual`), but if they wanted you to be able to use a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` or polymorphism via `Base` pointer/reference, they would have not declared the destructor `protected`. You'll probably have to ask the library documentation/author.

Comment: @KartikAnand Also from the core guidelines rules linked in the answer: "_We can imagine one case where you could want a protected virtual destructor: When an object of a derived type (and only of such a type) should be allowed to destroy another object (not itself) through a pointer to base. We haven’t seen such a case in practice, though._" So it would be interesting if you actually found a library validly making use of that given that the guideline is written by some of most senior experts on the language.

Comment: Not sure what the intention is in this case, but the Chromium project uses it here - https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/public/browser/web_contents_observer.h;drc=eb36519fa7a2d4e244a1a53b6147f367b6c55b54;l=834

Comment: @KartikAnand I am not familiar with the chromium code base, but this doesn't look to have a purpose. [Here](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/3789221) is a similar case where they also considered it "code smell" and changed it. Could also be that this is just written defensively. Making the destructor `protected` assures that it can't be destructed through a base class pointer from the outside and making it `virtual` assures that even if e.g. a `friend` or child still manages to do it, at least there won't be UB. But then why not allow it for anyone? Seems dubious.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would a `friend` or `child` be able to do the destruction through base class pointer ?

Comment: @KartikAnand Deleting another object is always possible and `delete this;` or similar is also allowed.